# Obtener las coordenadas en Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, geolocalización

tengo una aplicación que consume un JSON de una página de restauranes. Resulta que mediante la latitud y longitud, el aplicativo muestra los posibles resultados de restauranes en una lista. Lo que necesito es obtener las coordenadas actuales del usuario para buscar las posibilidades.

```
class Observer: ObservableObject {

@Published var  datas = [Datatype]()

init() {

    let url1 = "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/geocode?lat=-33.4592298&lon=-70.645348"
    let key = "c913841060ea614f7c0f5b5f120a21cb"


    print(url1)

    let url = URL(string: url1)
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue(key, forHTTPHeaderField: "user-key")

    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, _, _) in

        do {
            let fetch = try JSONDecoder().decode(Type.self, from: data!)
            print(fetch)



            for i in fetch.nearby_restaurants{

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.datas.append(Datatype(id: i.restaurant.id, name: i.restaurant.name, image: i.restaurant.thumb, rating: i.restaurant.user_rating.aggregate_rating, webUrl: i.restaurant.url))
                }


            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }.resume()
  }
}
```

Como lo puedo hacer? ya que si notan en el 'url1', se encuentra "lat" y "lon", mi idea es colocar variables de la ubicación actual para realizar la búsqueda, pero no entiendo como obtener las coordenadas. Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 0):

### Pasos a seguir

1. Importa corelocation.
2. Extienda el protocolo `CLLocationManagerDelegate`.
3. Cree una instancia de `CLLocationManager`.
4. Haz delegada de la instancia la clase controlador actual
5. Implementa la función del protocolo cuando se obtenga las coordenadas
6. Edita el fichero [`Info.plist`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050633/implement-cllocationmanagerdelegate-methods-in-swift/24056771#24056771) como se describe a continuación

### Cómo configurar Info.plist

A partir de iOS8 se requiere que una de estas dos siguientes entradas esté configurada en el fichero `Info.plist` para usar ubicaciones. El que uses depende de cómo pienses pedir la ubicación:

- Usa `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` para aplicaciones que desean
  usar la ubicación del dispositivo, incluso cuando la aplicación no
  está abierta y en uso.
- Usa `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` para aplicaciones que desean
  usar la ubicación del dispositivo solo cuando la aplicación está
  abierta y en uso.

**Nota**: Cuando agrega las entradas, antes de compilar y ejecutar, elimine la aplicación de su dispositivo y deje que realice una nueva instalación. Parece que si la aplicación fue autorizada, no volverá a solicitar su permiso y no verá que establecer las nuevas entradas. Antes de hacer una instalación se aconseja borrar y limpiar la aplicación para resolver esto.

Al configurar cualquiera de las entradas, aparece una ventana emergente en la instalación / primer uso de la aplicación.

### Un ejemplo de lo expuesto sería:

```
import UIKit
import corelocation

class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate{

@IBOutlet var gpsResult : UILabel

var manager:CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   manager = CLLocationManager()
   manager.delegate = self // Hace el controlador delegado de CLLocationManager
   manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest // Elige el grado de precisión
   manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() // Solicita la autorización
   manager.startUpdatingLocation() // Inicia la localización
}

func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:AnyObject[]) {
    println("locations = \(locations)") // Imprime las localizaciones
    gpsResult.text = "success" // Cambia el texto del label
}
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero no me funciona, y eso que hice todos los pasos que me dijiste :/